# Passing Pk or Slug to Generic DetailView in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django Class based views. I am trying to make a simple view to get details of a post. 
My views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, View, DetailView 
class GenreDetail(DetailView):
            model = Post
            template_name = "post.html"
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post'),
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', GenreDetail.as_view()),
    ]
```

Error that I get:

```
AttributeError at /2/memoirs-of-a-geisha-by-arthur-golden
Generic detail view GenreDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

So the pk or slug is not passed to the Generic Detailview. How do I pass that ? I assume from url it can pick up but it's not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

url patterns are checked in the order you define them

so here:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post'),
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', GenreDetail.as_view()),
    ]
```

...the first pattern is getting matched (because it does not end with `$` so the extra segment is just ignored)

...and that pattern only passes a single keyword arg

Generally it is a bad idea to have multiple url patterns pointing to the same view. If possible you should try and make a single regex (eg using [optional groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)) which handles the various cases of the url for a particular view. It's more explicit that way.

On the other hand, simply reversing the order of your patterns to put the more explicit one first would also work and be correct (this is the Django rule of urlpatterns!)

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', GenreDetail.as_view()),
        url(r'(?P<post_id>[^/]+)', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post'),
    ]
```

As @ozgur mentions you also need to tell the view to use `post_id` instead of `pk` by setting [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg)

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie which part doesn't work?  do you get an error?  this is an old answer so the interface may have changed in newer versions of Django, but the basic principle still applies

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/players/2818 does not match `players/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<nick>[-\w])$ [name='player_detail'] `. I've set the url_kwargs in the DetailView

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie that url is not expected to match that urlpattern... do you also have a more general regex like `players/(?P<pk>\d+)` in your urlconf?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to fetch details using either post_id or slug then your urls should be like this

```
url(r'post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
url(r'post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post_detail_slug'),
```

And your view should be like this

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView 

class GenreDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post.html"
    pk_url_kwarg = "post_id"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    query_pk_and_slug = True
```

For more details please read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.query_pk_and_slug).

Comment: Please note that `query_pk_and_slug` was introduced in Django 1.8

Comment: pk_url_kwarg = "post_id"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    query_pk_and_slug = True

Comment: very elegant solution here.  bravo.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have to tell `DetailView` that it should use `post_id` keyword in the URL instead of default ones `pk` or `slug` in order to get the object that will be displayed.

This can be done by setting [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) attribute:

*(Your url definition is also wrong, always end your url definitions with `$`. Below is the corrected version)*

```
url(r'(?P<post_id>\d+)$', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post'),
url(r'(?P<post_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', GenreDetail.as_view()),
```

The following urls will match given the url patterns above:

- /2
- /2/memoirs-of-a-geisha-by-arthur-golden

---

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView 

class GenreDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post.html"
    pk_url_kwarg = "post_id"
```

Alternatively, you can just change `post_id` to `pk` in your url so you don't have to touch anything in your view:

```
url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)$', GenreDetail.as_view(), name = 'post'),
url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', GenreDetail.as_view()),
```

Comment: Changing the name of the query parameter to `pk` in url also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<pk>/', views.GenreDetail.as_view(), name="post")]
```

For `slug`:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.GenreDetail.as_view(), name="post")
```

Comment: What are the generated urls then?